# How to remove __table from Tabel Knex.js select query

Tags: node.js, knex.js

How to remove `__table` from [Tabel](http://tabel.fractaltech.in/) `Knex.js select query`.

The select query returns all data i queried +`__table` but how can i remove `__table`.

My select query

```
table('TestSeriesModes').select('ID', 'Name', 'IsActive', 'IsPhysicalInventory', 'Code').orderBy('ID', 'asc').all()
```

Returning data

```
{
    "__table": "TestSeriesModes",
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Online",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsPhysicalInventory": true,
     "Code": "ON"
},
{
    "__table": "TestSeriesModes",
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Calling Tablet",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsPhysicalInventory": true,
    "Code": "CALTAB"
 }
```

Comment: Have tried without "all()" ?

Comment: @KaushikAndani if i try without all am getting an error.

Comment: refer this link - https://devhints.io/knex#elect-1 - will help you

Comment: @KaushikAndani am using Tabel ORM - http://tabel.fractaltech.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex doesn't even have that .all method (at least officially). Looks like you are not using knex directly here. Knex never adds anything like you have described (key called __table) to your resulting rows. Complete reproduction case would be useful, because now the post does not have enough code shown to be able to tell what is wrong with it.

To answer the query, you can for example use knex directly to get results without that key. Maybe you are using some ORM, which adds it or some other library.

Other way to drop it would be to filter it out from results afterwards for example by doing:

```
const filteredResults = results.map(res => {
    delete res.__table;
});
```

Or to use some library like ramda / lodash to filter extra keys from resulting objects.

Comment: Am using Tabel ORM here is the link http://tabel.fractaltech.in, Your answer is working perfectly but it is we are deleting  `__table` after its being queried, Is there any way to prevent this from `Tabel ORM`?

Comment: After executing this codes am getting [
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]

Comment: @SushinPv Add `return res` after delete line. More about map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @coockoo Thanks a lot